# A set $\Omega$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that $|z| < M$ whenever $z \in \Omega$. The set $\Omega$ is contained in some large disc.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

My complex analysis textbook says the following:

> A set $\Omega$ is **bounded** if there exists $M > 0$ such that $|z| < M$ whenever $z \in \Omega$. In other words, the set $\Omega$ is contained in some large disc.

Something about this definition doesn't seem right.

$|z| < M$ is an open disc centred at the origin, since an open disc centred at the point $z_0$ is defined as $D_r(z_0) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z - z_0| < r \}$; and so we have that a bounded set is $\{ z \in \Omega : |z| < M \} \subseteq \Omega$. In other words, the definition is saying that a set is bounded if every point in that set is in an open disc of radius $M$ centred at the origin. Am I correct in my understanding of this?

Therefore, this definition of a bounded set is specific to a disc centred at the origin.

Topologically speaking, I don't understand how this is a sensical definition for bounded sets? It seems to me that a definition of bounded sets needs to be more generalisable, rather than anchored to some arbitrary point, such as the origin.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if a set is contained in $D_r(z_0)$, then that set is contained in $D_{r+|z_0-z_1|}(z_1)$ for any $z_1$.
In other words, the 'anchor' is irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm, what you claim is true, but how does that make the anchor irrelevant?

Comment: In the sense that a set being 'bounded' does not depend on the choice of 'anchor' in the definition.

Comment: @ThePointer: what this answer is saying is that if a set is contained in some disk centered at $z_0$, then we can translate $z_0$ to any other $z_1\in\mathbb C$ and adjust the radius accordingly. The center of the disk (or the "anchor" point) is irrelevant since adding two finite numbers (the radius plus the distance to the origin, for example) will still be finite. Since the center of the disk isn't important, it is just convenient to let the center be $0$ and avoid having to care about $z_0$.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see it now. It is true by design (by definition). By definition, the disc must be large enough to encompass the two points that are furthest away, and so regardless of where you switch the anchor point (in other words, regardless of which point is set as the anchor point), it will still encompass the point farthest away from it, and so it will encompass all of the points in the set. And it is this way by design, since we require some $M > 0$ such that $|z| < M$ **whenever** $z \in \Omega$. Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: Perhaps better put: if a set is bounded with respect to some anchor, then it is bounded with respect to **any** anchor. With this in mind, we simply say it is bounded (irrespective of anchors).

Comment: @Clayton Yes, but we are setting $M$ to a specific (single) value so that this is true for all points $z \in \Omega$, rather than changing the value of $M$ depending on the point in question and therefore having multiple values for $M$, right? I ask because "adjust radius" makes it sound like the latter rather than the former. So in other words, we would select the $M$ which encompasses the two points in the set that are farthest away (based on how we define our metric (distance function)), because this will also encompass all of the other points?

Comment: Given a set $\Omega$, provided you can find a single $M$ that works for all $z\in \Omega$ $($in the sense that $|z|<M)$, then $\Omega$ is bounded. Of course, by what we've just shown, you could also find a single $K$ and some $z_0$ such that $|z-z_0|<K$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Ok, thanks for the clarification. So it seems that this value $M$ will always end up being the value that encompasses the two points farthest away (having set either of these two points as "anchor"), since that value will also of course encompass all of the other points? In other words, it is the minimum value that encompasses all of the points, regardless of anchor.

Comment: $M$ can be whatever large value works. You don't need to find a 'tightest fitting disc'. If there is *some* disc, however large, we're good. The problem of finding a 'tightest fitting disc' is interesting in its own merit but also much harder and nuanced.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Ok, got it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: In a general metric space $(X,d)$, we could define more symmetrically that $\Omega$ is bounded if there exists $M$ such that $d(x,y)<M$ for all $x,y\in\Omega$. Even then it turns out that we can pick an arbitrary point $x_0\in X$ and show that $\Omega$ is bounded iff there exists $M'$ such that $d(x_0,x)<M'$ for all $x\in\Omega$. In the given situation, we have a normed space and not only a metric space, hence picking the origin as base point and thereby working with the norm directly instead of with the metric derived from the norm is more natural.